# How to set regex matchers on PactDslJsonBody in consumer pact version 3.5.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pact, pact-jvm

When upgraded pact.consumer.version to 3.5.3, I am not able to create regex matcher on PactDslJsonBody. Below is code with version 3.2.8:

```
PactDslJsonBody requestBody = createJSONPact(requestBodyJSON, new 
PactDslJsonBody());
System.out.println("*****PactRequestBody****" + requestBody);

Map<String, Map<String, Object>> reqMatchers = new HashMap<String, 
Map<String, Object>>();
reqMatchers.put(".data.slot", createMatcher("regex", "\\S+"));
requestBody.setMatchers(reqMatchers);
```

Now in version 3.5.3 setMatchers function is giving compilation error since now it supports Category object. So how can I use Category object to set json body request matchers?

I need help with this!

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: getting compilation error at requestBody.setMatchers(reqMatchers) as in consumer  pact version 3.5.3 setMatchers(Map<String, Map<String, Object>> obj) is not supportive. It is replaced with setMatchers(Category obj).

Answer (score 0):

All of these new changes has been [documented properly within the repo](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-consumer-junit#building-json-bodies-with-pactdsljsonbody-dsl).  The Consumer DSL has changed to make it easier to specify which type of matcher you're trying to use.

Please review the readme link I provided to figure out your issue.

Cheers.

Comment: Link is outdated, current link is https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/tree/master/consumer/junit#building-json-bodies-with-pactdsljsonbody-dsl